# No internet, but can ping from cmd

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, ping, internet-connection

My internet was working fine, but one day it stopped working at all (I am using ethernet connection). It just says 'No internet'. I can `ping www.google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8.` but when I launch the browser none of the websites works.

I am using Windows 10.

The cable is fine, I tried different ones and no effect.

What I have already tried:

1. When `ipconfig /all` and for Ethernet adapter Ethernet it prints all the information. For all others (LAN, wifi) it says `Media state..............: Media disconnected`.
2. I run Network adapter troubleshooter and it reset the adapter. That didn't help either.

Could you please help me with it?

PS: I also cannot browse through WI-FI, even though when I use wifi it doesn't say 'No internet' - just 'Connected, secured'.

Comment: Is your browser configured to use a proxy?

Comment: @SamForbis I can ping both separately.

Comment: @spikey_richie how can I check that? 
I used Chrome/IE/Edge - none of that worked.

Comment: Are you using any antivirus software other than the one built in to Windows? How are you connecting to the internet? You seem to imply that you connect via an ethernet cable. Do other devices share your internet connection through the use of a router? If so, are any of them experiencing similar issues?

Comment: Hi, please check the following message:(1) Disable the firewall or other anti-virus programs to test (2) Check the configuration of your DNS server in command 'ipconfig /all' and 'nslookup 8.8.8.8' to check the client use what DNS server to resolve the address and conpare with the resule of'ipconfig/ all'

Comment: Can we see the output of the ping to www.google.com? You should be getting something like this: `Reply from 216.58.192.164: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=112`. Also, do you have any other machines on the network that are working?

Comment: @SamForbis no, no antivirus. No, I don't have any other devices to check that, neither I have a router.

Comment: I also updated a question - I cannot browse with WIFI also :(

Comment: @GloriaGu they use the same DNS server 193.210.18.150

Comment: @Meow_ly yes, that's what I get. Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0. No, I don't have any devices to check that. But since I cannot connect via WIFI also (I used hotspot from my iPhone) looks like the problem is with laptop...

Comment: I'm doubtful this will work because it says no internet, but I'd be interested to see if browsing to a known IP address works from your browser. What happens if you go to http://216.58.192.164/ in the browser? Same issue?

Comment: @Meow_ly yes. It's same issue

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have a proxy setup for the internet.

Open Powershell or CMD as Admin and run

```
netsh.exe winhttp show proxy
```

That should list any proxies setup. To remove run

```
netsh.exe winhttp reset proxy
```

---

Or check 'Internet Properties', CMD run

```
inetcpl.cpl
```

Go to the 'Connections' tab and look at the 'Dial-up/VPN settings'

See if you have anything setup and just select each and then click the 'remove' button.

Answer (score 0):

#### My internet was working fine, but one day it stopped working at all

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults (reboot required):

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: Thank you. This also didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

If you see:

```
nslookup google.com
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
```

Then set DNS servers to:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

Manual: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

1. [open network connection settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUOs6.png)
2. [set Google Public DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0n2x.png)

More images: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-pcs-dns-settings-windows-10

Comment: That also didn't help.

Comment: And now I can't even ping 8.8.8.8